# Apache POI shift row to last vs shift rows up

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to process excel files. I want to delete the specified line, and then found that the first method not wort, I mean the deleted row should be moved to the end of this sheet, but it still has not moved.

**Method1:**

```
sheet.shiftRows(rowNum, rowNum, sheet.getLastRowNum() - rowNum, true, false);
```

**Method2:**

```
sheet.shiftRows(rowNum + 1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), -1, true, false);
```

Anyone can help me?

**UPDATE**

After test, I found other prombel [Apache POI delete row and append row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62280390/apache-poi-delete-row-and-append-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using what `apache poi` version is method 1 even working? The logic is not the one for deleting a row. It only shifts the row `rowNum` to the position of the last row. So last row gets overwritten and row `rowNum` gets empty. This is not what I would call deleting a row. Furthermore this always leads to corrupt `Excel` files when `XSSF` (`*.xlsx`) is used. So clearly method 2.

But this one-liner will not always work. It only works if there are filled rows after the to delete row. If that is not the case, `rowNum + 1` will be greater than `sheet.getLastRowNum()` and it fails. In that case we should shift the empty `rowNum + 1` one up.

```
 void deleteRow(Sheet sheet, int rowNum) {
  if (rowNum > sheet.getLastRowNum()) return; // rowNum is outside the filled rows

  if (rowNum + 1 < sheet.getLastRowNum()) { // there are filled rows after the to delete row 
   sheet.shiftRows(rowNum + 1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), -1, true, false);
  } else { // there are no filled rows after the to delete row, so shift rowNum + 1 one up
   sheet.shiftRows(rowNum + 1, rowNum + 1, -1, true, false);
  }
 }
```