# Apache POI delete row and append row

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using `apache-poi(3.16 and 4.0.0)` to generate an excel file. I need to delete the specified line (remove row and move to the last row) and append the data after the last line. When I moved the line, I found that it did not work as expected.

These are my codes (rowNum < lastRowNum):

**shiftRows1**

```
sheet.shiftRows(rowNum, rowNum, sheet.getLastRowNum() - rowNum, true, false);
```

**shiftRows2**

```
sheet.shiftRows(rowNum + 1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), -1, true, false);
```

**appendRow**

```
setRowValue(sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1, objectArray);
```

**My Question**

1. `shiftRows1` + `appendRow` + `4.0.0/3.16` + `XSSF` : clear rowNum and delete lastRowNum
2. `shiftRows1` + `appendRow` + `4.0.0/3.16` + `HSSF` : clear rowNum and clear lastRowNum
3. `shiftRows2` + `appendRow` + `4.0.0` + `XSSF` : damaged file; after repair, delete lastRowNum and clear rows >= rowNum
4. `shiftRows2` + `appendRow` + `4.0.0/3.16` + `HSSF` : delete rowNum and can not append row(lastRowNum always equal to the lastRowNum before delete)
5. `shiftRows2` + `appendRow` + `3.16`  + `XSSF` : **working**

After test, the `shiftRows1` cannot be used. Why `HSSF` not update lastRowNum after `appendRow`? how can i achive it use `shiftRows2` and `3.16`?

Comment: `Sheet.shiftRows` always had, actually has and always will have bugs because of its complexity. You found multiple of them in different `apache poi` versions. Some are fixed in newest `apache poi 4.1.2`. But not all, see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?list_id=190011&product=POI. So at first you always should using newest `apache poi` version. And you should have a look at the bug list when using `Sheet.shiftRows`.

Comment: Yes, I will try your suggestions. In addition, I have dealt with this problem in other ways.

Comment: I tried `apache poi 4.1.2`, but it does not work with `HSSF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dealt with this problem in the following way(`apache-poi 3.16`):

```
private void removeRow(int rowNum) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
    if (row == null) return;
    sheet.removeRow(row);

    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    if (rowNum < lastRowNum) {
        // bad way: shift the removed row down
        sheet.shiftRows(rowNum + 1, lastRowNum, -1, true, false);
        // remove lastRow: avoid Sheet#getLastRowNum() return same value after Sheet#shiftRows
        if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) removeRow(lastRowNum);
    }
}
```